# Bootstrap textfield button add on with label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap code for showing a textfield with a button:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <label>Second Column</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
   </div>
   <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
```

I should get something like this:

[image]

But what I get is this:

[image]

I guess its because of the `<label>` tag.

> Any clue on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to move the `label` to outside the `.input-group`

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="field1">Second Column</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
   </div>
</div>
```